# How do I calculate the distance between a function and a point efficiently and generalizable?

Tags: optimization, graphing-functions, maxima-minima

for the purpose of plotting a function i want to calculate the (minimum) distance of a point to this function. (I want to calculate the distance of each pixel to the desired function)

As an example, lets take the function

$f(x) = x^2$

and the point

$P = (1,0)$

First, I calculate the distance to every point on the function:

$d = \sqrt{(x-1)^2 + (y-0)^2}$

$d = \sqrt{(x-1)^2 + (x^2-0)^2}$

$d^2 = x^4+x^2-2x+1$

Now I basically just create a minimalization problem out of this to get the minimum distance. I would form the derivative and solve it for 0 to get the minima of the distance and choose the smallest result (I minimize the square of the distance to make it easyer to calculate):

$(d^2)' = 4x^3+2x-2 = 0$

However, this is not very generalizable. Lets say, our function is not $x^2$ but rather something like $10 * sin(x)$. In that case the resulting distance function would have a lot of local minima. Also when i program this, i would need the computer to calculate derivatives of any function that i choose to plot.

How do graphing/plotting programs calculate this?
Is there not a simpler, more generalizable way to solve this problem? Maybe by leveraging the fact, that when we calculate the distance, only at the shortest distance we have exact 1 solution to the equation (think of a circle around the point intersecting the function)

I will be very thankful about your help!

Comment: I don't know programs that calculate distance from arbitrary plot to point. Equation $(d^2)'=0$ may be not solvable in closed form. Maybe some programs make numerical calculations not analytical. Maybe some programs can give wrong distance for some complex plots.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: This can be solved easily using [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier#:%7E:text=In%20mathematical%20optimization%2C%20the%20method,chosen%20values%20of%20the%20variables).

The answer:

You can consider the function you want to minimise as the distance(or it's square) from your point $P = (p_x, p_y)$:
$$ d(x, y) =  (x-p_x)^2 + (y-p_y)^2$$
and your constraint function as $g(x, y) = f(x)-y$.

Now all you need to do is find the critical points of $d(x, y) + \lambda g(x, y)$. You can generalise it to higher dimensions or other distances.

Also, I am obviously assuming the function $f(x)$ to be well-behaved here.